# How to create XML from JSON string in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a `JSON Encoded` string. I need to create `XML` from it.

Now what I am doing is, using `JSON PERL MODULE` I am decoding the string and that will create a Perl Array. Looping through the array and creating XML. It is kind of more coding.

Any module for this JOB?

That will automatically convert the JSON to XML...I googled it and I did not find any solution for this.

I know there is a module that will conver XML to JSON XMLTOJSON.

Comment: XML doesn't have a concept of arrays, object, strings, numbers. XML has elements, attributes and text. You'd need to define some mapping between the two.

Comment: That I know, but modules/plugin are written for all these. Minimize the amount of work done.

Comment: You do not understand: You haven't said what format you want. "XML" is not a format.

Comment: I asked some module available that will take care of this job. While passing the multidimensional array as an argument it will automatically convert to xml ?

Comment: "XML" is not a format. You can't "convert to xml". You need to be more specific.

Comment: You mean to say that, I should create a XML rather than telling word convert rite ?

Comment: Look at my question now ..

Comment: Sahal: Instead of getting angry, you might consider that ikegami might have a point. Looking at your question, one might as well produce XML that simply has the original JSON as literal element text.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov You don't need to talk about country code an all here...

Comment: @innaM I am not angry. The answer is below I accepted also.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Sometimes copy paste work better than learning those or understanding before we go. Time is also a matter in software industry. No one wait until you learn things. We Indians are more genius than any one else in the word. Might be like you said I am dump. But others!!!!

Comment: @ikegami Sorry you felt am rude. I am searching for some solution.

Comment: @Borodin Ohh is it... Attitude matters. That too in Russia!!!

Comment: I never said or thought you were rude. You simply haven't specified what you want yet. As I've already explained, XML has no intrinsic representation of any of the things JSON can represent, so you need to specify a more specific format.

Comment: "copy paste work better than learning those or understanding before we go <...> We Indians are more genius than any one else in the word". Just as I've said, epitome of "Indian code". Go ahead, flag this comment too - it isn't need much, I couldn't bury the guy better than he did himself anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please checkout, this might help u out!

[Link #01](http://blog.shaftek.org/2009/02/11/converting-json-to-xml-with-perl/)

From Blog [blogLink](http://blog.shaftek.org/)  author : yakovsh

Recently I had to work with Google AJAX API data which returns in JSON. For my purposes, the data needed to be in XML. While there is a CPAN module called [XML2JSON](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=XML2JSON) which is designed to do that, for some reason it chokes on my input. Instead, I adopted a much more simple technique from the [Google::Data::JSON](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Google%3a%3aData%3a%3aJSON) module as follows:

```
use JSON::Any;
use XML::Simple;

my $convertor = JSON::Any->new();
my $data = $convertor->decode($json);
my $xml = XMLout($data)
```

Comment: I do not have access to that link :(. Blocked by firewall.

Comment: Please consider re-wording this answer into your own words. You have basically copied an entire blog post. It is good that you have linked for attribution, but generally, you shouldn't copy an entire page like this.

Comment: @AndrewBarber as Sahal replied , he was unable to access that linked , as he was facing firewall which was blocking that link. so to help him out, i type down the material for his help.... read Sahal comments